# Python’: No such file or directory

Tags: xubuntu, python, python3, youtube-dl

Youtube-dl is months out of date in the repos so I installed it using [this method](https://www.linuxhelp.com/how-to-install-youtube-dl-on-ubuntu-19-04)

(though I changed the location to usr/bin/youtube-dl as that's what `which youtube-dl` showed)

but then I get

```
$ youtube-dl
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory

$ python2 youtube-dl
python2: can't open file 'youtube-dl': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

But it works if I enter

```
$ python2 /usr/bin/youtube-dl 
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

$ python3 /usr/bin/youtube-dl 
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]
```

I'm using Xubuntu 20.04, could someone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with 20.04 `/usr/bin/python` is no longer there. And youtube-dl starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

So what you can do is create the symbolic link yourself:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

And then it should work:

```
$ youtube-dl
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work:

$ sudo apt-get install python-minimal gives "the following packages replace it: python2-minimal:i386 python2-minimal" and

sudo apt-get install python2/python3-minimal both give "is already the newest version"

Comment: You're right. Beginning with 20.04, that no longer works. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, sorry about the delayed response. I came across another similar topic and I used the suggestion there which fixed it: sudo sed -i '1s/python/python3/' /usr/bin/youtube-dl

Comment: That works too, but you will have to do it after each upgrade of `youtube-dl`, because you are patching the program. The symlink in the answer is something you will do only once.

Comment: Ah I see, I wasnt aware, thanks for pointing that out